# Write a module that works both in nodejs and requirejs

Tags: node.js, requirejs

I wrote a small parser that currently works in node app, but wondering if there is a way that I can make a module that will work both in NodeJS app and client side app that uses requirejs?

`path/to/lib/index.js`

```
function someRandom(strings) {
  // we are doing something here
  return strings
}

exports.someRandom = someRandom;
```

Right now I'm getting this in client-side

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

I know that I can use node `requirejs` and then change the structure to use `define` but is there other way without adding node `requirejs`?

This is my `js/main.js` file

```
require(["path/to/lib/index"], function(something) {
    // will do something here
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I prefer to do it is to write all my modules in the AMD syntax (use `define`) and use [`amd-loader`](https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-amd-loader) to load them in Node. Note that this solution is not using RequireJS, even though the AMD syntax is used.

However, there's a way to do it without having to use the AMD syntax. You can use `r.js` to wrap your Node modules. For instance, if you put your tree of Node modules in `in`, you can do:

```
$ r.js -convert in out
```

This will create in `out` a tree of files that correspond to those in `in` but wrapped with the `define` call. You can then load these in the browser using RequireJS. There are limitations. Some are obvious, like not being able to use the Node modules that depend on the Node runtime (like `fs`, `child_process`, etc.). Some are more subtle, like the fact that you can't use `require(foo)` where `foo` is a variable (RequireJS will handle only string literals there). See the [documentation](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js#convert-commonjs-modules) for the details.

Comment: `amd-loader` I think I can go with this one :) Thanks!