# Can I write a CoffeeScript lib the same way for the server and client?

Tags: node.js, browser, coffeescript

I'm trying to write a modular library in CoffeeScript. I want to write the code once, and use it in the same way on the server (running Node in this case) and on the browser. How can I do this?

My code structure is like this...

- src/a.coffee
- src/b.coffee
- src/c.coffee

And my dependencies are like this...
`a` depends on `b`, `c` depends on `a` and `b`.

I've tried Browserify and requirejs, but I couldn't quite get there with it. I've also looked into Traceur but that's no use since I'm using CoffeeScript. I'm really at a loss, the only thing I can think of, is bundling it all up in one file and doing it traditionally as explained in this blog... https://alicoding.com/write-javascript-modules-that-works-both-in-nodejs-and-browser-with-requirejs/. I really don't want to do that, I'd probably just write it in Dart sooner than I would bundle it up like that. CoffeeScript is really letting me down with this particular issue.

Comment: So you've looked into Browserify and RequireJS but you were unable to use them for your task. Without knowing **why** they did not do it for you, chances are that people are going to propose to you solutions that lead to the same unsatisfactory results you had. By the way, the solution in the blog post you link to is terrible (this is the *diplomatic* word for it). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23418416/1906307) for a brief explanation of how you can do it. The only thing missing from that answer is the CoffeeScript angle.

Comment: CoffeeScript is compiled into Javascript,if you can use js, you can use coffee.

Comment: @Louis They didn't work as I wanted because it was CoffeeScript. RequireJS needs the require-cs plugin but I couldn't find a way to use that consistently on the browser and the server. Ok thanks for the link.

Comment: @osrpt I don't want to sound ungrateful, but I'm more than capable of reading the first line of CoffeeScript's website...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to resolve this. I ended up using https://github.com/jrburke/amdefine.