# Protractor + RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, protractor

Please, show me how to use Protractor with RequireJS.

code works

```
var dentalConfig = require('./conf/dentalConfig.js');
var login = require('./pages/login.js');    
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    baseUrl: dentalConfig.baseUrl,
    specs: [
        'pages/company.js'
    ],
    onPrepare: function () {
        login();
    }
};
```

but if i put exports.config inside of requirejs()
protractor throw error:

```
c:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\configParser.js:184
fileConfig.configDir = path.dirname(filePath);
TypeError: Cannot set property 'configDir' of undefined.
```

this doesn't work

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');    
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: './',
    nodeRequire: require
});    
requirejs([
        'conf/dentalConfig',
        'pages/login'
    ],
    function (dentalConfig, login) {
        exports.config = {
            seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
            baseUrl: dentalConfig.baseUrl,
            specs: [
                'pages/company.js'
            ],
            onPrepare: function () {
                login();
            }
        };
    }
);
```

Comment: No! In that answer RequireJS using on browser side, but i wont to use it on server side for Protractor tests.

Comment: Fair enough. The problem though is that your title and the way you open the question set the wrong tone. A question now: why are you using RequireJS in the server?

Comment: Why not ? RequireJS works fine on NodeJS, and I like its AMD format

Comment: Why not? Because why complicate things if you don't *need* to complicate them? I do use RequireJS in Node to test some of my modules. However, I don't use it unless I must use it. It is, for instance, quite possible to [load AMD modules in Node without using RequireJS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23418416/1906307). (Before you ask, let me point out that `amd-loader` is a trivially simple module loader compared to RequireJS.)

Comment: What version of protractor are you using?  Are you seeing any other errors logged to the console?

Answer (score -1):

Your config file should look something like this..
exports.config = {

```
     seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
     directConnect: true,
     framework: 'jasmine',

     specs: ['TestScript name that has to be executed.js'],


     jasmineNodeOpts: {
            showColors: true,
            defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
            isVerbose:true,
            includeStackTrace:true
        },


     capabilities: {
         'browserName': 'chrome',


     },
```

}